# Group values in same column in R

Tags: r

I am still relativly new to R and need some help on the following problem. 
I have da dataframe that looks smiliar to this (but way more complex)

```
Token1  A    B   E
Token2  A    F   D   G  
Token3  C    F   E
Token4  B    A   F
```

What I want is grouping each unique value that appears in one row so that one column only contains a value, if true for a row, and NA if not, like this:

```
Token1  A    B    NA   NA  E   NA  NA
Token2  A    NA   NA   D   NA  F   G  
Token3  NA   NA   C    NA  E   F   NA
Token4  A    B    NA   NA  NA  F   NA
```

I haven't found anything helpful so far...how do I get to the above result?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Thanks to all, but the actual DF is a lot more complex and contains several thousand possible values in all columns (I just used A, B, C etc. to simplify the problem), so the solutions won't seem to work...
How do I group them all (I'm aware that there will be MANY single columns)?

Comment: I think in this case, it really matters how your data set looks like. Could you `dput`it?

Comment: I tried to use dput(), but even for only n = 1, the output is HUGE (the dataframe has about 250 columns in total, if thats helpful)

Comment: Use this: `df <- data.frame(Token=c("Token1", "Token2", "Token3", "Token4"),
           Col1=c("A", "A", "C", "B"), Col2=c("B", "F", "F", "A"), 
           Col3=c("E", "D", "E", "F"), Col4=c("", "G", "", ""))`

Comment: I had the structure of the empty cells in Col4 in mind, when I asked for the `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
cols = unique(unlist(df[-1]))
cols = as.vector(sort(cols[!is.na(cols)]))

cbind(as.vector(df[,1]),
      t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(u) ifelse(cols %in% u[!is.na(u)], cols, NA))))
#  [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]         [,8]      
#1 "cat"   NA       "dog.01" NA        NA         NA        NA           NA        
#2 "bird"  "cat.01" NA       NA        "robin.01" NA        NA           "eagle.01"
#3 "horse" NA       "dog.01" "pony.01" NA         NA        "unicorn.01" NA        
#4 "dog"   "cat.01" NA       NA        "robin.01" "bird.01" NA           NA        
#5 ""      NA       NA       NA        NA         NA        NA           NA
```

**Data:**

```
df=structure(list(Lemma = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse"), class = "factor"), Sim = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "cat.01", "dog.01", "pony.01", "robin.01"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bird.01", "cat.01", "unicorn.01"), class = "factor"), X.1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "dog.01", "eagle.01", "robin.01"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Lemma", "Sim", "X", "X.1"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution -- very minor addition you should consider: add

cols = cols[order(cols)]

before the cbind statement -- this will put the letters in order

Comment: Thank you, but this works with the sample dataframe, but unfortunatly not with the original (very large) that I import with read.csv2, is there any way to apply it?

Comment: Again to answer your question please provide dput(head(read.csv2(...)))

Comment: Small sample: structure(list(Lemma = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"bird", "cat", "dog", "horse"), class = "factor"), Sim = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "cat.01", "dog.01", "pony.01", 
"robin.01"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "bird.01", "cat.01", "unicorn.01"), class = "factor"), 
    X.1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "dog.01", 
    "eagle.01", "robin.01"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Lemma", 
"Sim", "X", "X.1"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: In this data.frame, what's the expected `token` column? The `lemma` column?

Comment: It should look similar to the above example, that means one column for each values in all rows and columns with the value if true for a row in this column and NA if not...

Comment: Edited. Beware that the data.frame you gave me contains factor (hence the vector conversion)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want such a structure, but you can try `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package after collapsing all of the non-token columns into a single string.

Here's an example with the sample data from Colonel Beauvel's answer.

```
df2 <- cbind(df[1], New = do.call(paste, c(df[-1], sep = ",")))
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit_e(df2, "New", ",", mode = "value", type = "character", drop = TRUE)
#   Lemma New_ New_bird.01 New_cat.01 New_dog.01 New_eagle.01 New_pony.01
# 1   cat             <NA>       <NA>     dog.01         <NA>        <NA>
# 2  bird <NA>        <NA>     cat.01       <NA>     eagle.01        <NA>
# 3 horse <NA>        <NA>       <NA>     dog.01         <NA>     pony.01
# 4   dog <NA>     bird.01     cat.01       <NA>         <NA>        <NA>
# 5                   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>        <NA>
#   New_robin.01 New_unicorn.01
# 1         <NA>           <NA>
# 2     robin.01           <NA>
# 3         <NA>     unicorn.01
# 4     robin.01           <NA>
# 5         <NA>           <NA>
```

You'll have to just drop the "New_" column, which results from having some empty columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, for all letters:

```
df <- data.frame(Token=c("Token1", "Token2", "Token3", "Token4"),
       Col1=c("A", "A", "C", "B"), Col2=c("B", "F", "F", "A"), 
       Col3=c("E", "D", "E", "F"), Col4=c("", "G", "", ""))

df2 <- data.frame(df[, 1], t(sapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(i){
  toupper(letters) %in% c(t(df[i, -1]))
})))

names(df2) <- c("Token", toupper(letters))

for(i in 2:27){
  df2[, i][df2[, i]==T] <- names(df2)[i]
  df2[, i][df2[, i]==F] <- NA
}

df2
```